# How to limit the number of many in the one-to-many relationship in the constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle21c

[image]

One B can have only one A, but one A can be appeared in B up to 3 only.

Suppose I have the following code to create new tables:

```
create table A (
A_id number constraint Aid_pk primary key);

create table B (
B_id number constraint Bid_pk primary key,
A_id number constraint ref_fk references A(A_id));
```

This is the standard one-to-many relationship, how can I change it to limit the max number of references?

Comment: I think the only option available is to use trigger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle: constraint preventing insert more than N (variable) rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467640/oracle-constraint-preventing-insert-more-than-n-variable-rows). Or [Modeling One-to-Constant Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235544/modeling-one-to-constant-relationship)